# SPI and I2C protocol in android

Tags: android, i2c, spi, android-things

I'm developing a sensor dongle in small size like wireless mouse dongle. can I send sensor data to android device over USB port with I2C or SPI protocol? the microcotroller doesnt support USB protocol
I've found something about i2c in android but I'm not sure if that solves my problem or not!!!!
https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/i2c
thanks.
[SCHEMATICS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNWHh.png)

Comment: You can't send this data over USB, but you can send it via exactly I2C or SPI.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko, with an adapter it can be done, for example Diolan DLN-2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the driver for SPI and I2C it's part of Android Things. That is not your standard Android and can not be installed on just any device. It only supports Raspberry Pi 3 and iMX7D. Also, it has been discontinued, so no new updates will ever come.

Can't you just use UART?  Other options would be Bluetooth, even as a beacon, broadcasting the message, or just WiFi uploading the values directly to a service like Firebase. There are very simple microcontrollers that can do that, like NRF52, ESP8266 or ESP32. Both have a Firebase library.